# Java ServerSocket Ban IP-address

Tags: java, serversocket, ddos

How can specific IP address be prevented from connecting to a Java server through `ServerSocket`?

The official approach suggested on multiple forums is:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        InetAddress address = socket.getInetAddress();
        if (isBanned(address)) {
            socket.close();
            continue;
        }
        //execute business logic here...
    }
```

But in this approach a `Socket` object is created for every new client (even for banned clients).

A `Socket` object is extremely heavyweight: at least 100 bytes per new object.

There is nothing stopping clients from connecting thousands of times per second and causing DDOS attack.

How can banned clients be handled safely in `ServerSocket` without creating new objects in memory?

Comment: You can't. This is a job for a firewall, not `ServerSocket`. But it is the operating system socket itself that is 'heavywieight', not 100 bytes of a Java object.

Comment: NB "The official approach suggested on multiple forums" is a contradiction in terms. Forums are not official.